# Oracle SQL Delete Record without affecting child tables

Tags: sql-delete, delete-row, oracle12c

I've got many tables in my database, but my problem is concerned to this two tables:

[image: ERD]
    .

The definiton of those is:

```
Employee (EmployeeID_PK, FirstName, LastName, Email, ...)
Order    (OrderID_PK, EmployeeID_FK, OrderDate, MenuID, ...)

*_PK = Primary Key
*_FK = Foreign Key
```

Now I want to **delete** a Employee so that he's not able to login anymore, but I still need to have his orders and his attributes (like FirstName, LastName, ...).

So the data should stay in the tables, but the employee shouldn't be able to login anymore.

I know that adding a column 'isactive' to Employee would be a solution, but I don't think that it's the best way to do this. Please tell me anyway, if it's the only way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is preventing a user from logging in related in any way to the contents of tables in your database? Locking a user account has nothing to do with rows in a table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you said one option is to have a `status` column - 1 for active, 0 for inactive, 2 for login blocked may be.

If you don't want to take that approach, you can create a copy of both primary and secondary tables ( `Employee_Archive` and `Order_Archive` with equivalent pk and fk constraints) and move both the sets of data there. That way the user can no longer login, no data is lost and the integrity is retained.

If there is however too much data in `Order` table though, you may still only have the first approach left - to add a `status` column.

Comment: So, you mean that if I want to delete a employee so that he isn't able to login anymore, I only delete the record from the active_employees table?

Comment: Believe you will not be able to delete any entry in the active-employees if there is an fk-constraint. Hence you'd need to move the orders to an archive table as well. That is don't delete, move data. And when you are moving employees, you may have to move data for orders as well due to fk constraint. Which is why I said adding a status column and modifying application implementation to look for the status is a much better idea.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the fast answer. I also tried the "2nd table approach", but I think that it's the better way to add the isactive column now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of situation should **not** be addressed by modifying existing tables (such as, by adding columns to tables or whatever).

Rather, this is **exactly** what "locking user accounts" is for. You can lock the user's account, so she or he can no longer log in, but her or his schema (meaning all her or his objects, such as tables, indexes, views etc.) remain exactly as they are.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-6A8D4A59-6DB2-4662-BA4C-05B914D31B4F.htm#ADMQS12042

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4003.htm#SQLRF01103